# Jekyll - How do you get rendered content of posts?

Tags: html, jekyll, blogs

I need to get the rendered content (without html tags) of some posts in Jekyll. When I do 'post.content' It returns the full HTML instead of the rendered text. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strip_html` filter `{{ post.content | strip_html }}`